# Customizing okay google command

Tags: actions-on-google

We are designing a chatbot for our project and in order to integrate that chatbot with voice recognition facility, we are planning to embed our chatbot with google assistant. But the problem is after embedding to invoke our chatbot within google assistant we have to say okay google followed by our customized phrase. My question is, is there any way to change the okay google command to our customized command to invoke our chatbot through google assistant?. Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you implementing the Google Assistant? Actions on Google? Assistant SDK for devices?

Comment: Actions on google

Comment: Then no, you will not be able to change the hotword.

Comment: What if we use sdk

Comment: You'd need to handle a lot of the Assistant calls yourself. You could include your own hotword to open the microphone, although we don't provide any tooling for you to do that. Additionally, it wouldn't be surfaced in the Assistant on other surfaces, you'd be creating your own surface.